# Does Blender support the glTF format?

Tags: export, import, gltf

Is the import/export of [GLTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF) files is going to be supported or is there a python script that can handle that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an exporter available here:
https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf

While its work-in-progress, its already usable for exporting textured meshes.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the Khronos Group also has an official exporter for version 2.0: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter

Comment: Thanks I wasn't totally clear on the differences. I did notice that's Kupoman's still supports v1 but Khronos' is v2 only.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to see some movement around this topic. Seems like the Khronos one is GLTF 2.0 only (no 1.0).

Answer (score 7):

Blender 2.80+ now ships with [glTF-Blender-IO](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) pre-installed.  This is a combination of the original Khronos glTF exporter with Julien Duroure's glTF importer.

The Blender Manual has [documentation on importing and exporting glTF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html), including a section on how to get physically-based (PBR) materials to glTF.

Answer (score 4):

There is also seems to be alpha version of importer: https://github.com/ksons/gltf-blender-importer

Answer (score 0):

Verge3D comes with a well-maintained and open-source Blender to glTF (GLB) exporter. Check it out [on GitHub](https://github.com/Soft8Soft/verge3d-blender-addon).